# WCF NULL vs Not present distinguish

Tags: wcf

In WCF I have a nullable int property on person object. What i want to do is that when the client explicitly passes NULL then i should update the database table to null, if they do NOT send this optional parameter then ignore.

Example code below. What i have foind is that there seems to be no easy way to do this.

```
[ServiceContract]
 public interface IPersonRepository
 {

  [OperationContract]
   string UpdatePerson(Person person);
}    



public class PersonRepository : IPersonRepository
{

  public string UpdatePerson(Person person)
  {
    return person.ToString();
  }

}
[DataContract]
public class Person
{

   [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
   public int? Age{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I would do this by adding an explicit boolean property to the DataContract - something like ForceAgeNull.  Alternatively, send it as a string, and interpret an empty string as "force to null".

Comment: thanks joe, yeah i thought about that as well, i would prefer not to but i guess that maybe the option i would have to take.